# Qual é o nome genérico do campo de busca no Xamarin pra utilização no teste automatizado?

Tags: xamarin, testes

Alguém pode me ajudar nessa questão?
Não estou conseguindo utilizar o mesmo código de testes pra iOS e para Android.
O nome do campo de busca que foi encontrado não é o mesmo, ou seja:

```
Syntax in iOS - app.Query(x => x.Class("UISearchBarTextField"));
Syntax in Android - app.WaitForElement(x => x.Id("search_src_text"));
```

O que me parece o genério é o **search_src_text**, mas este não funciona no iOS.
Dês de já agradeço.

Comment: Está utilizando alguma ferramente específica para os testes? É um teste automatizado de UI?

Answer (score 1):

Use a propriedade AutomationId, e acesse o elemento dessa forma

XAML:

```
<Button AutomationId="MeuBotao" Text="Toque aqui" />
```

CSharp:

```
app.Query(c=>c.Marked("MeuBotao"))
```